# setMetaKeyword() not working to insert data for categories magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, category

Following is the code for updating categories, but the **meta keywords in not getting updated**

```
 $categoryFactory = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
          $categories = $categoryFactory->create()
                      ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                      ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$category_ids));

          $tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalog_category_entity_varchar');
          $tableDesc = $resource->getTableName('catalog_category_entity_text');

          foreach($categories as $category)
          {

             $metatitle= $csv[$id]['category_id'];
             $metadesc= $csv[$id]['meta_description'];
             $metakeyword= $csv[$id]['meta_keywords'];
             $description=$csv[$id]['meta_description'];

             $category->setWebsiteIds([1]);        
             $category->setMetaTitle($metatitle);
             $category->setMetaDescription($metadesc);
             $category->setMetaKeyword($metakeyword);


              $category->save();

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue trying to update and save product meta values in an product save after observer, but was able to get it to work by using $resource->saveAttribute(). Try this kind of thing:

```
// Ugly object manager use is NOT recommended, using here for brevity only.
// Use DI instead.
$categoryFactory = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');

$categories = $categoryFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$category_ids));

$resource = false;
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $category->setWebsiteIds([1]); 

    if (!$resource) {
        $resource = $category->getResource();
    }

    $meta_attributes = ['meta_title', 'meta_description', 'meta_keyword'];
    foreach ($meta_attributes as $meta_attribute) {
         // Rename CSV rows to match meta_attributes exactly
         $category->setData($meta_attribute, $csv[$id][$meta_attribute]);
         $resource->saveAttribute($category, $meta_attribute);
    }
}
```

This worked well in my product update observer code (product save after):

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $resource = $this->_product->getResource();

    $meta_attributes = ['meta_title', 'meta_description', 'meta_keyword'];

    foreach ($meta_attributes as $meta_attribute) {
        $value = $product->getData($meta_attribute);
        if (empty($value)) {
            $new_value = $this->_getDefaultMeta($meta_attribute);
            $product->setData($meta_attribute, $new_value);
            $resource->saveAttribute($this->_product, $meta_attribute);
        }
    }
}
```

Why $resource->saveAttribute() and not just $product->save()?

- product->save() on productSaveAfter creates infinite loop
- productSaveBefore didn't work because something in Magento code reverts the product meta values after they are updated

Also, $resource->saveAttribute didn't work on productSaveBefore, (because of the pesky meta-value-reverting Magento code) but works on productSaveAfter.